# API Gateway connection timeout at beginning

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

My question will be a little bit vague, because i can't find the problem I have

To resume, i've create an API with Express and put it in an Elastic Beanstalk environnement

After that i've recreate that API but this time, i used Serverless to put it directly in an API Gateway. So both API exist (one on Elastic Beanstalk, proxified on an API Gateway, and the other directly on API Gateway with Serverless)

But the problem is, since both API exist, it sometimes happens that I have a request timeout on both API on a query that normally works.
I don't really know how to explain it better, but randomly, i'll have a request which take a long time and fall in timeout. But the most strange is, if i execute this request again, during the first still running, this new request will work and take the expected time it need

I can't delete one of those two APIs for now because they're used in production environment.

To specify what my API does, it connect to a mongoDB and just make a findOne on an item

But when the request fall in timeout, it seems that the connection is not even made.

I thought the problem was that the two APIs were connecting on the same database and that was causing the problem, but i don't know

And when I re-deploy my Serverless API, it'll not fall in timeout during for a certain time

If anyone has an idea, or need more details, don't hesitate to ask me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is unclear, but I'm guessing all the timeouts are coming from your serverless/AWS Lambda deployment. It sounds exactly like what happens with AWS Lambda cold starts. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/execution-environments.html If that isn't the case, then you are going to need to look at your API server's logs to find any errors or timeouts associated with these issues.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but when the timeout happens, it happens on both APIs, at least, the last time i saw this, it was on both. That's why i think the problem comes from MongoDB. I'll try to watch logs, but since the problem happens randomly, I don't know when I could get those error logs

Comment: Sounds like you're going to have to do some log diving on API Gateway logs, CloudWatch Logs for the Lambda function, and app-specific logs for the EB app.

Comment: Could be a database connection timeout happening or something. The only way to know for sure is to look at the logs that occurred during the time the issue happened.